# Assembly language: The different segments....are they stored in the RAM?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86-16

I am new to assembly language. Whenever I initialize a memory segment for example: a code segment or a data segment, it is said that the OS allocates a portion of the memory for that. However, I am really confused by what my book means by "portion of memory". Is the code segment in the RAM to be specific?

Comment: Are you talking about x86? If yes, are you talking about segment *registers* or the segment representations an assembler may allow you to describe? Unfortunately "segment" is a quite overloaded term in the x86 literature.

Comment: yes...i am referring to x86. The segment registers hold the address of the memory segment. My question is, when I write instructions in the assembler to initialize for example a Data segment....is that data segment created inside the RAM?

Comment: When you do something like `mov ax, @data / mov ds, ax`? No, the segment is loaded from the executable by the loader if any, what you are doing is setting up the registers so they point to the correct location. In an OS like DOS, you can access all the memory - so by appropriately setting the segment registers you can "allocate" (or better use) all the memory you want.

Comment: When I do something like this: msg db 'hi$' in the .data segment ..... does this cause a portion of the RAM to be allocated for the data segment?

Comment: That directs the assembler to output the bytes 'h', 'i', '$' in the containing segment during the generation of the object/executable file thereby increasing its size. The loader will then load the whole segment (and hence those bytes) - since the segment has grown the loader needs to allocate more memory in order to load it. Short answer: Yes, indirectly.

Comment: For an excellent web reference for Assembly see [**The Art of Assembly Language Programming**](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/artofasm.html). While it is primarily written for 8086, all principles are 100% applicable to current assembly programming. The only differences are register sizes, calling conventions and syscall numbers for x86_64. The reference describes the memory layout and pipelines in great detail.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a number of references in the comments, but I wanted to add that there are different states to consider in answering your core questions:

1. When you compile and link your code, it writes and stores the result to disk as an executable or library.
2. In the disk image, the compiler/linker encodes information about the various segments.
3. When the executable/library is loaded, the OS sets up the segments you declared into RAM and marks the memory pages that the segments occupy with the appropriate privileges (as [noted by fuz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43248411)).
4. Whether or not the entire content of a segment is read and loaded into RAM depends on numerous factors and optimizations offered by the platform you are running on. You can research that elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Typically, all segments are loaded into RAM. we distinguish various segments for efficiency and security reasons. For example, we distinguish text and data because text is executable but not writable whereas data is writable but not executable.

On embedded platforms, some sections might live in an EEPROM or flash ROM instead of RAM so they don't waste precious RAM. For the programmer, the only difference is that you can't write to such sections unless you do some special preparations.

Comment: I am referring to x86. So when I write instructions in the assembler to initialize for example a Data segment....is that data segment created inside the RAM? Or when I initialize the code segment (by stating .CODE)...are the instructions saved inside the RAM? The questions are silly but books really don't specify this

Comment: Yes! Both are being loaded into RAM in the final binary.